# Nginx serving images

Tags: image, nginx

Trying to generate image if it's not exists via Nginx redirect to script, but have problems with this simple issue. 
Wrote following config (tried different variants, this is the last), but it still wont works.

```
location /img/(\d+)\.(jpg|png|gif)$ {
       root /path/to/img_dir;
       expires max;
       add_header Pragma public;
       add_header Cache-Control "public";
       try_files $1.$2 http://site.com/generate_img/$1.$2;
}
```

Also used this code insted of `try_files`:

```
if (!-f $document_root/$1.$2) {
     rewrite ^ http://site.com/generate_img/$1.$2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. try_files doesn't support external redirects. Only internal redirects. 
   You need to use an  internal location.
2. Your location is not an regex based location. So the captures are useless. Try:

   ```
   location ~* ^/img/([[:digit:]]+)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
      try_files $1.$2 /generate_image/$1.$2;
   }
   ```

I'm assuming that `generate_image` is on the same server.

Comment: I still recieve 404 page. Tried to set redirect to simple html page, but had no changes. Maybe it't about document root path?

Comment: `location ~* ^/image_dir/([[:digit:]]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ {
 root /path/to/domain/dir;
 try_files /image_dir/$1.$2 /test.html;
}` 
tried this config